# Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 5 and input n_features is 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

** I am predicting a target value from a machine learning algorithm. The user will give basic features and they will be a classified value. I created my own dataset for this. All user values are in a list; after that, they are converted into an array and passed through the predict function. At that time it is failing with a "Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 5 and input n_features is 1" error **

```
split_index = int(len(db)*.4)


x_train= db.iloc[:,:5][:-split_index]
x_test= db.iloc[:,:5][-split_index:]
y_train= db.iloc[:,5][:-split_index]
y_test= db.iloc[:,5][-split_index:]
# Create linear regression object
regr = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2,random_state=1)
```

**using RandomForestClassification **

```
regr.fit(x_train,y_train)
print("PLEASE READ INSTRUCTION")
lista=[]
print("""
kindly enter 5 features in sequence
1.number of leaves: (seedling has upto 15 leaves)
2.height of seeding: (in centimeter upto 20cm)
3.color of seedling: (white 100, reddish 101, brown 102, green 103, faint green 104, yellow 105)
4.texture of seedling: (smooth 0 rough 1)
5.length of leaf: (in centimeter upto 20cm)""")
for x in range(0,5):
    a=int(input("enter feature "))
    lista.append(a)
#print(lista)
#import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#rp= pd.DataFrame(lista)
#print(rp)

dc=np.array(lista)
dc=dc[:,np.newaxis]
#print(dc)
regr_pred = regr.predict(dc)
print(regr_pred)
#print(type(regr
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dc` array has the shape=(5, 1). So I would recommend you transpose it

```
dc = dc.T
```